# What does the grey portion of the experience bar denote?

Tags: new-world

The experience bar *sometimes* has a grey portion after the already gained experience (circled):

[image: bar]

As stated, this grey portion isn't always present.  What does the grey portion indicate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [this](https://amp.reddit.com/r/newworldgame/comments/q2lhd7/why_is_there_two_exp_bars_yellow_and_grey/) Reddit thread and [this](https://www.rockpapershotgun.com/new-world-leveling) guide, the grey bar represents how much Rested XP you have accumulated. Rested XP can be obtained by logging out while in a town/settlement (the Reddit threads stated it starts accumulating after 8 hours of inactivity, but not sure if that’s accurate).

Rested XP is essentially bonus XP you can take advantage of towards your character level; it does not affect crafting or trade skills. When you have Rested XP, any task that provides character experience is doubled until the Rested Xp is consumed.