# What does the blue bar in the experience bar mean?

Tags: new-world

Sometimes there is a blue bar that is above the regular yellow experience bar:

[image: bar]

What does this bar mean and what contributes towards it?

Comment: I saw some rumors about it being tied to  territory standing (https://www.reddit.com/r/newworldgame/comments/qeqnfw/what_is_the_small_green_bar_above_my_xp_bar/) but I'm level 60 and running around to a few different zones I cannot see any other bars, obviously no xp bar either, so I don't think it's that either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed this bar for the first time yesterday after being offline for a few days. I'm fairly close to levelling up, and the usual grey bar rest xp indicator is completely full i.e. all the way to the edge of the screen.

My suspicion is that the blue bar is indicating the 'rest xp' that has accumulated beyond your current level.

E.g. if you're currently level 34 and 90% of the way to level 35, your xp bar would be completely full to the end with the 'grey bar' representation of rest xp, and this blue bar is indicating what percentage of the xp from 35-36 is being covered by rest xp.

Possibly this means that rest xp is capped at the amount for you to level up once plus one full extra level, which does sound plausible.

Comment: This seems like a good possibility. The only thing I can think of though is the blue bar is somethings nearly the length of the entire experience bar, which I don't think you can accumulate that much rested XP bonus.

Comment: @TimmyJim Contrary to my comment in the another answer, I can agree/confirm that it actually *is* rested XP. I haven't been able to play for the last few days. When I logged in yesterday, my rested XP was nearly filled to the end of the bar. So I decide to test Kayndarr's theory. I logged in this morning, and the green bar that you posted was now there. I leveled up, and the green bar disappeared and then appeared as the grey bar

Comment: @Wondercricket I've been meaning to try and test this, be every time I am close to leveling I either accidentally level, or don't give it enough time to gain the rest XP bonus, but this seems to be what most people believe it is, and seeing that it is within the XP bar, I don't see what else it could be.

Comment: @TimmyJim I didn't take any screenshots which probably would have been useful, but I was offline for about a week and when logging in I had enough rest xp for the grey bar to be right to the end, plus a full blue/green bar all the way across the screen, plus a *second* blue/green bar that sat just on top of the first that went about half way across the screen. Once I levelled up, the 'full' extra bar went away, and I had the grey bar across the whole screen plus the single half-way blue/green bar left.

Comment: @Kayndarr surprised they give you that much rested xp!

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search told me it's a "rested" bar. When you log out, it will fill up so that when you log back in you will start to gain xp at a faster rate. There is a similar mechanic in WoW, for reference.

EDIT: As wondercricket pointed out, I was thinking of the grey bar. I will leave this answer here in case anyone looking for if finds this post first.

Comment: The grey XP bar is different than the blue bar the OP is asking about: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/391330/124566

Comment: Yea the grey bar is not what I am asking about (I did previously ask about that too though as linked above!)

Comment: The blue/green bar seems to also be rested XP also - see [this comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/391623/what-does-the-blue-bar-in-the-experience-bar-mean/391680?noredirect=1#comment550642_391680)

Answer (score -2):

The blue bar indicates your Rest XP, when you gain xp there is a bonus of XP because of the Rest XP